# Recursion limits and singular Jacobians

Tags: equation-solving

As a warm-up exercise, I am trying to solve the following system of equations:

$$ p = \frac{\text{exp}(q)}{\text{exp}(q) + \text{exp}(1 - q)}, \hspace{0.5em}q = \frac{\text{exp}(1-p)}{\text{exp}(1-p) + \text{exp}(9p)};$$

where $\text{exp}()$ denotes the exponential function. (I have also the constraints that $p \in [0, 1]$ and $q \in [0, 1]$ but it may be simplest to disregard them for now.)

It is easy enough to find approximate solutions using Wolfram Alpha: I find that $p \approx 0. 31 $ and $q \approx 0. 11 $ (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20%5Bp%20%3D%20exp%28q%29%2F%28exp%28q%29%20%2B%20exp%281%20-%20q%29%29%2C%20q%20%3D%20exp%281%20-%20p%29%2F%28exp%281%20-%20p%29%20%2B%20exp%289%20p%29%29%2C%20p%2C%20q%5D)). However, for some reason I cannot find these solutions using Mathematica (which I am new to).

More concretely, I tried the following:

```
$RecursionLimit = 10^5

FindRoot[{p = Exp[q]/(Exp[q] + Exp[1 - q]), 
  q = Exp[1 - p]/(Exp[1 - p] + Exp[9 p])}, {{p, 0.3}, { q, 0.1}}]
```

Unfortunately, I received the following messages:

[image]
[image: List item]

Does anyone know how I can proceed? I tried disabling the recursion limit (see code) but this hasn't worked. I also tried changing the initial values, again without success. I guess this problem should be easy -- so what am I missing?

Many thanks in advance for any ideas or pointers!

Comment: Use [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) (`==`) instead of [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) (`=`). See the docs of [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html?q=FindRoot) too.

Comment: Thanks so much! I can't believe I have been so stupid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Corey979, equations use [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) rather than [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)

```
eqns = p == Exp[q]/(Exp[q] + Exp[1 - q]) && 
   q == Exp[1 - p]/(Exp[1 - p] + Exp[9 p]);
```

[`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) will find the exact solution in terms of [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expressions

```
sol = Solve[eqns, {p, q}, Reals]
```

[image]

Verifying the solution

```
eqns /. sol[[1]] // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

The approximate numeric values are

```
solN = sol // N

(* {p -> 0.31278, q -> 0.106424} *)
```

To use [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) requires that a constraint be placed on `p` and/or `q`

```
NSolve[eqns, {p, q}, Reals]

(* {{p -> 0.31278, q -> 0.106424}} *)
```

Similarly,

```
NSolve[eqns && Element[p, Reals], {p, q}]

NSolve[eqns && Element[q, Reals], {p, q}]

NSolve[eqns && 0 < p, {p, q}]

NSolve[eqns && 0 < q, {p, q}]

NSolve[eqns && 0 < p && 0 < q, {p, q}]
```

Comment: Thanks this looks incredibly helpful!